# Transition effect on image change (add/remove class) with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5, transition

I need help with simple transition effect on hover/out on div box to change first image `.image-main` to second `image-hover`.
It works fine now, but I don't know how to add mouseOn/mouseOut effect (simple opacity fade out would be enough).

I want to use JS because in this feature I want to add some extra action. CSS hover effect also destroyed `.img-fluid` activity.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">

  <div class="product-box">
    <div class="product-box__image">
      <img class="img-fluid image-main" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff">
      <img class="img-fluid image-hover" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/00cc00/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="product-box__content">
      <p class="text-center p-3">
        hello description<br>on hover - change image too
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.product-box').hover(
  function() {
    var main = $(this).find('.image-main');
    var second = $(this).find('.image-hover');
    main.removeClass('image-main');
    main.addClass('image-hover');
    second.addClass('image-main');
    second.removeClass('image-hover');

  },
  function() {
    var second = $(this).find('.image-main');
    var main = $(this).find('.image-hover');
    second.removeClass('image-main');
    second.addClass('image-hover');
    main.addClass('image-main');
    main.removeClass('image-hover');
  }
);
```

CSS:

```
    .product-box {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    .image-hover {
      display: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qsyr1te7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just set the first image to full opacity and give it an opacity transition.

```
.image-main {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then you can set opacity to 0 on `.hovering`.

```
.hovering {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now you can simply add or remove the hovering class to the first image.

```
$('.product-box').hover(
  function() {
    var main = $(this).find('.image-main');
    main.addClass('hovering');
  },
  function() {
    var main = $(this).find('.image-hover');
    main.removeClass('hovering');
  }
);
```

Hope this is what you were after. Cheers!